# How do I make a theme have SQUARE instead of ROUND windows?

Tags: gtk, customization, appearance, themes

How can I make my favorite theme (i.e, Orta) have **square** instead of **rounded** window corners?

Comment: isn't an option to make it so, in it's settings manager?, otherwise i think you would have to edit the theme manually.

Comment: I thought so too! I opened up the OrtaSettingsManager.py, and looked around a bit, but didn't find anything.

Comment: I found an answer here; http://askubuntu.com/questions/638399/how-to-make-ambiance-title-bar-corners-squared/638409#638409

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Appearance > Themes > Customize and in windows border section choose Orta-Squared. You can right click and go to change desktop background as well for accessing appearance settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sagarchalise, thanks! I actually meant to do this with the Elementary window-border, but decided on using the Orta-Squared anyway.