# How to make ambiance title bar corners squared?

Tags: themes

Is there a way to make the corners squared in ambiance or another theme for ubuntu 14.04?

I prefer the look and feel of squared corners.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit unity.css;**

1. Open a `terminal` with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`t`;
2. Type in the `terminal`;
   `cd /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/`
3. Now type;
   `sudo -i gedit unity.css`
4. In `gedit` *(text editor)* press `Ctrl`+`f` & in the `search` `field` that appears type;
   `border-radius`
5. You should see the search phrase highlighted, our interest is in the proceeding text;
   `: 6px 6px 0 0;`
6. Modify this text so that the line reads;
   `border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;`

   *I recommend keeping the px indicators in this line for easy future reference*
7. `Save` and `Exit` the document.
8. `Logout`& back in, or change the theme & back again, enjoy!

This method should work with other themes as well, replacing Ambiance in the directory above with the appropriate theme package name;

`/usr/share/themes/*theme-name*/gtk-3.0/apps/`

Then modifying the corresponding `unity.css` file as before.

Keep in mind that for some themes there may be another border-radius entry in a separate css class within the same `unity.css` document that has to do with the window when it is not in focus.

This class will have the name;

`UnityDecoration.top:backdrop`

the `border-radius` value here will also need to be changed in order for square corners to work for windows currently unfocused.

Comment: `sudo gedit ...` [*might* make a mess](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application), so `sudo nano ...` or using `gksudo` may be better

Comment: post updated, I hope this didn't cause anyone any issues... funny to answer my own question, goes to show what a bit of poking around can offer.

Comment: It should be fine :D (the entire running GUI program as root = stuff ends up owned by root is a bit controversial ([e.g.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632798/why-gedit-cant-be-used-with-sudo)). It just annoying when it makes a mess. N.B. I think `sudo -H` can be used as well as `gksudo`